Migrating MySQL db with minimum downtime: how to migrate partially?
I have a 150+GB database I need to migrate to a new host. Most of the data is event logs, which I already "hard" partitioned, moving all past years (10 GB per year, for a sense of scale) into a completely separate, secondary database. Having slimmed down the main database to about 10 GB total, I can probably migrate it quickly enough. Once I have the current data on the new host, operating correctly, I'll migrate the archives. But I wonder if there's a better approach I could be taking:

Is it possible to cold-backup-and-restore individual databases? There's this "tablespace" thing that keeps not recognizing my files, how do I force a starting mysqld to just use the database folders (I have file-per-table options set) and not try to use any "common file" nonsense?
Is it possible to manage table partitions like a cold backup, that is, copy just the new partitions, and later copy the older ones as needed?

